# Return JSON from ajax call into HTML div

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I've got my javascript ajax call returning json and I'm trying to put it on the HTML page.

I use this code:

```
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;++i)
        {
            $('#main').append('<div class="name">'+response[i].name+'</>');
        }
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert(response);
          }
        });
```

However it seems to print json to my console just fine but I dont get anything returned to the website.

I have a div to collect it in:

```
<div id="main">Test</div>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

EDIT: The console log response is this:

```
{totalPages: 0, firstPage: true, lastPage: true, numberOfElements: 0, number: 0, …}
columns: {columnIds: Array(3)}
firstPage: true
lastPage: true
number: 0
numberOfElements: 0
oberonRequestXML: [null]
oberonResponseXML: [null]
summaryData: {totals: Array(3)}
totalElements: 0
totalPages: 0
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: post the whole ajax call please

Comment: You'll probably be able to see exactly what's going wrong if you debug this code in your browser. Without seeing the whole thing myself, it's probably something to do with the JSON being a string and not an array, so your loop isn't actually running the append code.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Ive added response

Comment: So that explains it: your response is not an array, but a plain object, so your loop does not loop (there is no `length`)

Comment: @JamesWillson You are still going to get better results by looking at your code in your browser's debugger. F12 will open up your dev tools and from there you can either put a break point in your ```success``` handler or use a ```debugger;``` statement.

Comment: @tricot Sorry I'm a bit new to this. Does it mean it's not proper JSON?

Comment: It does not even have the property you want.

Comment: No, it's proper JSON, but it's not an array of objects that you can loop through.

Comment: It is proper JSON, it is just nothing like what you seem to expect. As you can see in the console, the structure does not have a `length`, nor are there any `name` properties to be seen. So... what can we say? It is like you expected apples, but ordered pears...

Comment: @trincot I'm really stuck then. Can you please give me a tip what to do next. Do I need to convert my object into an array first or something?

Comment: You should read the documentation of whatever service URL you are calling. It should explain what it returns. Then see if that matches with what you *need*. If not, look for another service you can call on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, your JSON response is not an array -- there is no `length` property, so your loop does not loop. Moreover, you seem to expect an array with objects that have a `name` attribute. This is nowhere to be seen in the response you get.

Assuming you are calling the right JSON service, the only information you can iterate over is stored in two attributes: `columns.columnIds` and `summaryData.totals`. So you would get *something*, if you code it like this:

```
console.log(response);
for (var i=0;i<response.columns.columnIds.length;++i) {
    $('#main').append('<div class="name">'
                 + response.columns.columnIds[i] 
                 + ': '
                 + response.summaryData.totals[i] + '</div>');
}
```

This assumes that these values are primitive values, which is not clear from the response you got.

But again, this will not output `name` property values, as they do not appear in your JSON as far as is visible in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats really helpful